# Send whatsApp message using background Service without opening whatsApp

Tags: android

I am trying to build a background service in which I can send message from my whatsapp to the other user's whatsapp.
I've tried this code

```
PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    try {
        String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + "+91 7*********" + "&text=" + URLEncoder.encode("hhellow User", "UTF-8");
        i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            startActivity(i);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But it is again redirecting me to whatsapp and ask me to send the message. I don't want to open my whatsapp screen, message should directly be send to the user (in background).
I know this question is already asked but I didn't get my answer all are redirecting me to whatsApp.

Comment: I would spam others phone if this was possible.

Comment: Whatsapp won't allow such service which could result in spamming

Comment: yes you are right but from some Travel & Local. apps i could receive messages on my whatsApp registered mobile number how they are achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [WhatsApp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012) there are only two ways to send text

- Using Url
- Using Intent

In both cases users have to click send button explicitly to send the message.

So as of now it is not possible to send message directly using any background service without clicking send button from WhatsApp itself.

Comment: From some Travel & Local. apps i could receive messages on my whatsApp registered mobile number how they are achieving this.

Comment: They might manually send the message to each user or they might be using broadcast message feature. But for that too you have to enter the app using intent and press the send button. There is no way you can automate the WhatsApp message without explicitly pressing the send button as automation of messages can create a huge security issue for WhatsApp.

Comment: A lot of users ask for registration per day and i don't think they will manually send confirmation messages to each users on their whatsApp because it'll be so lengthy process to send message manually.

Comment: I have gone through the WhatsApp FAQs and documentation, haven't found any method to automate messages. You can check the link given in the answer itself. Trust me they don't support any stuff like this as of now. But in case you found some solution please let me know too as it can be pretty handy feature ;)

Comment: And can you please give me the link of  travel sites or your local sites which send WhatsApp message on user registration.

Comment: I have snap of hotel booking where I am getting messages on my whatsApp.

Comment: @RahulSharma Oyo rooms automatically send a message when booking confirms

Comment: when you use google voice it try saying "send msg to rahul " it automatically sends msg without interacting with whatsap.

Comment: I tried to use google assistant to do like this and it works, but how can I do like this using java or flutter.